# C# VSTO Word Addin, need to open a document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, vsto

I have an c# Addin and need to open a document from sharepoint.

Previous to this code I have a context created and logged to this sharepoint site.

I know I could open a filestream but then I clould not save as a PDF file in the site/library/folder

```
 var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
 _clientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>");

 ...
 ...

 Word.Document activeDocument = Application.ActiveDocument;
 Word.Document document = Application.Documents.Open("https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>/<library>/<folder>/<file.docx>", false);
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the file locally on the hard drive then use a local file path for the `Documents.Open` method. Consider your VSTO add-ins as a regular .net application where you can use the [System.Net Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net?view=net-5.0) which provides a simple programming interface for many of the protocols used on networks today. The `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` classes form the basis of what are called pluggable protocols, an implementation of network services that enables you to develop applications that use Internet resources without worrying about the specific details of the individual protocols.